# javascript match() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, match

I'm trying to count # of lines of a pre element and I'm using this:

```
var numlines = $('#mypreelement').text().match(/\n\r?/g).length + 1;
```

it works, but in some situations I get a error

> Error:
>   $('#mypreelement').text().match(/\n\r?/g) is null

this only happens on certain pages, but these pages don't have anything different from the ones on which it works, besides content of course...

Why?

Comment: The answer from this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea) has a regex for matching cross-browser hard returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means it couldn't match any of them, and `null` does not have a `length` property.

So try this...

```
if (var lines = $('#mypreelement').text().match(/\n\r?/g) != null) {
   var linesLength = lines.length + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[MDC RegExp Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> If the regular expression includes the
>   g flag, the method returns an Array
>   containing all matches. If there were
>   no matches, the method returns null.