# Max lines textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have found some scripts that limit  the lines used in a textarea like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var lines = 10;
        var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');
        var newLines=0;

        $('#rev').keydown(function(e) {

            newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
            linesUsed.text(newLines);

            if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
                linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                linesUsed.css('color', '');
            } 
        });
```

It works fine when you hit enter and limits it to 10 .But the problem occurs when you type sentences that are so long they automatically go to a new line without the \n and when you copy paste a text, then it fails to limit the lines used.

does anyone know how to fix this.

**Important**: solution needs to work for a textarea

Comment: have you tried calculating the `line-height` instead?

Comment: I've tried something, have a look at my answer...

Comment: what do you want it to do when you paste text, do you want the text cut off anything that goes beyond the limit...?

Comment: ok, I updated my answer, check it out! And don't forget to accept it as a correct answer (big checkmark below the voting buttons), if you think it is the one! ;)

Comment: not sure about you, but I haven't found anything solving this with a textarea specifically, although I'm generally quite good at searching... any reasons why you **absolutely** need to use a textarea?

Comment: nope thats why i put a bounty on it. no i dont necessarily need it but i would like to see a solution for it i am sure someone knows how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try doing it using this logic:

### JS :

```
var limit = 3; // <---max no of lines you want in textarea
var textarea = document.getElementById("splitLines");
var spaces = textarea.getAttribute("cols");

textarea.onkeyup = function() {
   var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");

   for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
   {
         if (lines[i].length <= spaces) continue;
         var j = 0;

        var space = spaces;

        while (j++ <= spaces) 
        {
           if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;  
        }
    lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
  }
    if(lines.length>limit)
    {
        textarea.style.color = 'red';
        setTimeout(function(){
            textarea.style.color = '';
        },500);
    }    
   textarea.value = lines.slice(0, limit).join("\n");
};
```

Here is the [**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/9x5Fb/116/)

Comment: I see you're "artificially" applying a line break to the textarea, however this will be hard to manage with different fonts... it's not a bad solution though, I must admit.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so it will reach the end of the text area?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't figure out how to calculate the height of only the text inside a textarea, so I used a `contenteditable` div instead. Hope you like this solution.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="rev" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    cursor:text;
    border:1px solid #000
}
#rev {
    line-height:20px;
    outline:none
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').click(function() {
        $('#rev').focus();
    });

    var limit = 3;
    var lineHeight = parseInt($('#rev').css('line-height'));

    $('#rev').keydown(function (e) {
    var totalHeight = parseInt($('#rev').height());
    var linesUsed = totalHeight / lineHeight;

        if (e.keyCode == 13 && linesUsed >= limit) {
            $('#rev').css('color', 'red');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#rev').css('color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO YOU CAN FIDDLE WITH](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q4U9/3/)**

### **MAJOR EDIT**

Following the OP pointing out I actually forgot to address the most important, I updated my code. I basically removed the check for the enter key and allowed the delete and backspace keys in case the text goes over the limit as follows. You may have to fiddle around with it a little to make it fit to your exact needs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').click(function() {
        $('#rev').focus();
    });

    var limit = 3;
    var lineHeight = parseInt($('#rev').css('line-height'));

    $('#rev').keydown(function (e) {
    var totalHeight = parseInt($('#rev').height());
    var linesUsed = totalHeight / lineHeight;

        if (linesUsed > limit) { // I removed 'e.keyCode == 13 &&' from here
            $('#rev').css('color', 'red');
            if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) return false; // I added this check
        } else {
            $('#rev').css('color', '');
        }
    });    
        
    // I added the following lines
    $('#rev').on('paste', function () { 
        if (linesUsed > limit) {
            $('#rev').css('color', 'red');
            if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) return false;
        } else {
            $('#rev').css('color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q4U9/5/)**

Comment: Thanx for the effort but this doesnt solve the problems, i still cann copy paste and it wont work for long sentences.

Comment: happy I could help to get you on the right track... ;)

Comment: you misunderstood: you don't apply this to a textarea, you replace the textarea with this

Comment: ... and I wouldn't be surprised if this could even be implemented with a textarea, but don't expect everything to be written by someone else, you have to do your homework too!

Comment: ...nonetheless, purely from the question's perspective, I believe this is still the correct answer, the fact that you cannot implement it has nothing to do with this specific question, therefore I do not believe it is fair from you to take back the correct answer check...

Comment: but i want it to be open in case someone has a another answer

Comment: the problem when i try this with the textarea is that the totalHeight always stays the same therefore the linesused is incorrect

Comment: again, like I said, this **will not work** with textarea! my solution is a different one, but it is a solution that at least **works**!

Comment: I have done some more testing and research, but there is simply no solution I could find that would accurately calculate the height or number of lines in a textarea...

Comment: type 3 rows of X-es, place the cursor in the middle of any of them rows and hit enter :D

Comment: and you break the limit of having 3 rows

Comment: @JaakKütt true that, well, it's far from being the perfect solution... have a look at Aditya's it seems that one is a quite good one...

Answer (score 2):

It's too much work to try to figure how many lines based on the number characters in each line and the textarea width (does the textarea have wrapping off or not? font size, different letter widths, spaces, etc...). The easiest way is to have two textareas (one visible and one not - height set to 0) with the same width and font styles and check the scroll height of the invisible textarea.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/SKYt4/1/

HTML

```
<textarea id="visible_textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="hidden_textarea"></textarea> <!-- hidden by setting the height to 0 -->
<div id="used_lines"></div>
```

CSS

```
textarea {line-height:16px; /* line height to calculate number of lines */
    width:150px; /* need to match width */}
#hidden_textarea {height:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    margin:0px;
    opacity:0;}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#visible_textarea').keyup(function(){
    $('#hidden_textarea').val(this.value);
    // checking how many lines
    var lns = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('hidden_textarea').scrollHeight / parseInt($('#hidden_textarea').css('line-height')));

    if (lns > 10) {
         $('#used_lines').css('color', '#ff0000');
    }
    else {
        $('#used_lines').css('color', '');
    }

    $('#used_lines').html(lns+' lines');
});


$('#visible_textarea').change(function(){
    $(this).keyup();
});
```

Comment: 1. why do you need a hidden textarea to calculate the height? 2. you did not provide a solution to prevent further typing. 3. you're currently also allowing the resizing of the textarea which will break this code...

Comment: The way this script works is by dividing the scroll height of the hidden textarea over the line height. Since the scroll height minimum value is the element height, we have to set the height to 0 to get an accurate scroll height. To stop further typing, you can add a keydown event that checks the number of lines and prevent the user for further typing. You can stop the resize by setting the css rule resize: none;

Comment: i know exactly how i'd do it, but the explanation to it is missing in your answer, except for the "why the hidden textarea" - that one was to satisfy my curiosity... ;)

Comment: Problem: On some browsers (Chrome is where I noticed this), `.css('line-height')` returns a non-int value such as `normal`. Solution: put something you know will be one line high in, and get the height: `$('#hidden_textarea').val("A"); var text_height = document.getElementById('hidden_textarea').scrollHeight;`
Then you can divide by `text_height` to get the number of lines.

Comment: Also, the hidden textbox gets a scrollbar which causes it to wrap at a slightly different place than the visible textbox. Add `overflow-y: hidden;` to the `#hidden_textbox` CSS to fix.