# Code works in jsfiddle but not in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using code from [Max lines textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731394/max-lines-textarea) to create a textarea with only 9 lines and this code works perfectly on my jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/cityFoeS/3j48cpzn/ The textarea will not limit the textarea to 9 lines like I want it to.

my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: black;
}
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    font-family: courier;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
div {
    font-family: courier;
    color: white;
    line-height:20px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 29px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    left: 10px;
}
</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = 9; // <---max no of lines you want in textarea
var textarea = document.getElementById("splitLines");
var spaces = textarea.getAttribute("cols");

textarea.onkeyup = function() {
   var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");

   for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
   {
         if (lines[i].length <= spaces) continue;
         var j = 0;

        var space = spaces;

    while (j++ <= spaces) 
    {
       if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;  
    }
    lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
  }
if(lines.length>limit)
{
    textarea.style.color = 'red';
    setTimeout(function(){
        textarea.style.color = '';
    },500);
}    
   textarea.value = lines.slice(0, limit).join("\n");
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10</div><textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="splitLines" onpaste="return false;"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what problem are you experiencing exactly? Error messages? Weird behavior? You should edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: Is this all in an `<html>` and `<body>` tag? JSFiddle does this automatically for you, but you have to do it yourself on your own HTML page.

Comment: @Danieboy I put it in now, thank you for notifying me

Comment: @JonathanLam it does have it but it still does not work

Comment: @RobertZamboni Can you post the HTML page code instead of the JSFiddle code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in JSFiddle, you have the option "Load Type" set to "onload" under the JavaScript options.

In your code, however, the JavaScript runs immediately, before the HTML — this will cause the error (and this is what I get when running it as a standalone HTML page):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

There are two solutions:

1. Moving the `<script>` tags to the end of the `<body>` tag. For example:

   ```
   <body>
       <!-- all your visible HTML elements -->
       <script>
           // all your JS code
       </script>
   </body>
   ```
2. Encapsulating all the JavaScript in a `window.onload` function or a `$(function() {})` (for use with jQuery). For example:

   ```
   <script>
       window.onload = function() {
           // all your JS code
       };
   </script>
   ```