# How to check if text area is empty or not in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have text area box ,I need to check the data when we enter the text in the text area.I written change method but that is not working 
here is the code.

```
<textarea (change)="textAreaEmpty(textValue)" #textValue></textarea>
```

component

```
 textAreaEmpty(text:string){
      if(text.length > 0)
        console.log(text);
  }
```

I also need to check how many rows user entered in the text area.i dint find any solution in anuglar2 ,I am able to get the data with jquery or javascript,but i don't want to use that. i want to use it in angular 2,Can any body help me?

Comment: `textAreaEmpty(textValue.value)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea

Comment: thanks its working.but change method is not calling when entered some thing in the text area.if i click outside of text area method is calling.

Comment: use `input` event instead of `change`. So `(input)="textAreaEmpty(textValue.value)"`

Comment: thanks yurzui ,the input event is working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *I am able to get the data with jquery or javascript,but i don't want to use that. i want to use it in angular 2,Can any body help me?*

Use `[ngModel]` if you want to do it more "Angularish"...

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textValue" (ngModelChange)="textAreaEmpty()"></textarea>
```

**TS:**

```
textValue: string = '';

textAreaEmpty(){
  if (this.textValue != '') {
    console.log(this.textValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

`textValue` is not a value in this case. It's the whole input element so if you'd like to check if it has it's own value, you need to change your html as follows:

```
<textarea (change)="textAreaEmpty(textValue.value)" #textValue></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Validation for `new-lines`, `white-spaces` or `null`**

```
if(value.trim().length === 0)
   console.log('No input found')
```

**Run code snippet to test**

insert `new-lines` and `white-spaces` but you'll not get any output on focus-out from input field

```js
document.getElementsByName("text")[0].addEventListener('change', onChange);

function onChange(){
  if (this.value.trim().length != 0) {
       console.log('Here is your output: ')
       console.log(this.value)
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea name="text" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Write and check"></textarea>
```