# Determine number of lines if TextArea which wraps the text

Tags: user-interface, javafx

How can the line count be determined, if a TextArea wraps the text by setting `setWrapText(true)`? With line count I mean the number of lines the user gets visualized in the whole TextArea inclusive scrollable content.

Neither splitting the text by `\n` nor asking the paragraph count didn't work, since the wrapping has nothing to do with actual line splits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea

Comment: @AliSajid - this is entirely irrelevant as 1. It is about JavaScript and **not** Java/JavaFX; and 2. It does not account for wrapping, only counting the number of lines in the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution thus far, the core principle centered around the fact that the line height returned by the `FontMetrics` class in javafx is (marginally) off of the actual line height determined by a `Text` node, which resulted in the basic idea of using this type of node as a helper.

**Count lines with active wrap text**

Basically determine the actual line height by using a helper `Text` node for measurement, resetting and restoring the wrapping width on that helper and recording the change in height.

**Count lines without active wrap text**

This is the easiest: In that case the size of the `paragraphs` property corresponds directly to the number of lines:

Putting it all together it could look something like this:

```
  /**
   * Calculates the current amount of rows in the textarea regardless 
   * of "wordWrap" set to {@code true} or {@code false}.
   * 
   * @return the current count of rows; {@code 0} if the count could not be determined
   */
  private int getRowCount() {
    int currentRowCount = 0;
    Text helper = new Text();
    /*
     * Little performance improvement: If "wrapText" is set to false, then the
     * list of paragraphs directly corresponds to the line count, otherwise we need 
     * to get creative...
     */
    if(this.textArea.isWrapText()) {
      // text needs to be on the scene
      Text text = (Text) textArea.lookup(".text");
      if(text == null) {
        return currentRowCount;
      }
      /*
       * Now we just count the paragraphs: If the paragraph size is less
       * than the current wrappingWidth then increment; Otherwise use our
       * Text helper instance to calculate the change in height for the 
       * current paragraph with "wrappingWidth" set to the actual 
       * wrappingWidth of the TextArea text
       */
      helper.setFont(textArea.getFont());
      for (CharSequence paragraph : textArea.getParagraphs()) {
        helper.setText(paragraph.toString());
        Bounds localBounds = helper.getBoundsInLocal();

        double paragraphWidth = localBounds.getWidth();
        if(paragraphWidth > text.getWrappingWidth()) {          
          double oldHeight = localBounds.getHeight();
          // this actually sets the automatic size adjustment into motion...
          helper.setWrappingWidth(text.getWrappingWidth());
          double newHeight = helper.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
          // ...and we reset it after computation
          helper.setWrappingWidth(0.0D);

          int paragraphLineCount = Double.valueOf(newHeight / oldHeight).intValue();
          currentRowCount += paragraphLineCount;
        } else {
          currentRowCount += 1;
        }
      }
    } else {
      currentRowCount = textArea.getParagraphs().size();
    }
    return currentRowCount;
  }
```

Hope this helps!