# Textarea that automatically adjusts its own font-size according to content & its length

Tags: javascript, textarea, font-size

This has been asked, but as it seems not for Javascript.

I would like to create a TextArea that has two sets of font sizes, one for when it contains less than 3 lines and one for when it contains more than that.

The only problem is that not only will the number of lines in the Textarea affect the chosen font-size, it will also be the amount of content, as when someone just enters a straight line of text without even a single newline, the Textarea will break the lines (using another wrap where horizontal scrolling becomes available is not a solution, unfortunately).

I created a detailled jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/kF9LY](http://jsfiddle.net/kF9LY/)

How can i measure the .value content of the Textarea in a fashion that will give me a clear calculation of the lines used, either by newlines or by content exceeding the width of a single line (and thus being displayed in the second) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the number of lines as you are describing cannot be measured as far as i know.

you may be able to detect on a key event whether the textarea's scrollHeight has become greater than its height however, meaning that a scrollbar has appeared, and you can then adjust the font size as needed.

Comment: Finally i managed to find a solution that is based on measuring scrollHeight. I was lucky it worked even with overflow: hidden. It was not easy as i had to do the calculations after each keypress by simulating the adding of another character. As i use a non fixed-width font, i chose to add a capital 'W' character to the textareas content and then measure what happened after that. Afterwards i would remove the extra character. While at first it felt like a dirty approach, it turned out to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can find the number of lines from one of the answers in the question, [How to get number of rows in <textarea >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760629/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-textarea).

Comment: I didnt find this! Shame! I will try the solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761203/1018787) and if it works will accept this as answer

Comment: Sorry but using this approach i was unable to get a proper result.