# Count number of rows inside a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As shown in the image below, I have several div inside a div (outer div). I need to count the number of rows the outer div have. In this example the row count is 5.

Note:The inner div is floated left and its content is created dynamically.

Does anyone has any ideas?[image]

Comment: Have you use a plugin to create that layout, such as Masonry?

Comment: you should provide us the html structure.

Comment: Lookin for something like:
`$('#outerDiv .leftFloatingDivs').length` ?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I am using isotopes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071278/gwt-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-div

Hope this helps !

Comment: @Homungus, I am using isotopes.js, I will have no idea which div will be placed in the left side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AT9Ye/1/)

```
var minLeft = null, rows = 0;
$('div div').each(function () {
    var left = $(this).offset().left;
    if (left <= minLeft || minLeft==null) {        
        rows++;
        minLeft=left;
    }
});
console.log(rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
var parentX = $('#containerDiv').position().left;
var rows = 0;

$('#containerDiv div').each(function(){
  if( $(this).position().left == parentX ){
    ++rows;
  }
});

alert('Num of rows: ' + rows );
```