# Jquery change textarea styles when user starts fourth line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea with a background, set by css. I want to remove this when the user has started the 4th line.

HTML

```
<textarea rows='7' cols='60' style='background(image.png)'></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(textarea).css("background","#fff");
```

I just need a trigger

Thanks

Comment: And you've tried... what?

Comment: nothing. I don't know how to trigger it

Comment: more solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760629/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-textarea

Answer (score 2):

give id for textarea and

```
   var text = $("#myTextArea").val();   
        var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        var count = lines.length;

        if(count>3){
        //your code to change background
        $(textarea).css("background","#fff");
        }
```

it may help you.

Comment: `\n` on its own is enough for the split, but this doesn't cover wrapped lines.  For instance, if a user types 120 characters in the first line, the cursor will actually be on the third row of the textarea.

Comment: @JackRenshaw wrap the above in a keyup event on your textarea