# Replicate textarea animation functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My JS is limited, and I am having trouble replicating `<textarea>` functionality I have seen in the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) framework (scroll to the `<textarea>` section).

I essentially want my `<textarea>` to expand smoothly based on the `.val()` of the `<textarea>`. Exactly like the example in the link I provided.

My code is below:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  $(this).animate({height: 'auto'}, 250);
  $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [code they use](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/forms.js#L121-L187) or take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761203/145346) on how to get the number of rows in a textarea; once you have that, you can calculate the height.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you are adding an automatic height at the first keyup(), then on the next keyup() it will still be auto.

I think you have to get the line number like [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea), get the `line-height`, and calculate the appropriate height for each `keyup`and `keydown`.

So maybe something like this (missing a moving scroll fix I think) :

```js
// Should be in a JS utility file
String.prototype.lines = function() {
  return this.split(/\r*\n/);
}
String.prototype.lineCount = function() {
  return this.lines().length;
}

// The code
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'textarea', function () {
  var loElem = $(this),
    lsValue = loElem.val();
  loElem.animate({minHeight: lsValue.lineCount() * 14}, 250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```