# Align multiple divs created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script which, for every line in a text file, creates a button with a name and a .innerHTML. I have attempted aligning them in a grid (2 buttons wide by x buttons tall) next to a large text area, however have not been able to figure out how to. Could someone assist me?

CSS

```
.textArea{
    width: 700px;
    height: 520px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background-color: black;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
}
.buttons {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea class ="textArea"id="output" name="consl" cols="100" readonly="true"></textarea>
```

JS

```
let btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.innerHTML = title
btn.name = ">>>" + customs[1]
btn.className = "customButtons"
document.body.appendChild(btn)
```

Image of what I am aiming for (not to scale):
[image]

Comment: Can you give a visual idea of what you want to reach ? to be honest it is not so clear ;)

Comment: could you please provide more details like your HTML or JS code?

Comment: In you question object you talk about multiple divs but into its body and even into the code you talk about buttons. Maybe you want to make your question a bit more coherent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a codepen sample where you can find something similar to what you try to achieve : https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/XWqWomj

If you type text on the text area, buttons will appear on the right, 2 new buttons each time you add a new line in the text area by pressing 'enter'
(I am unsure if you wanted the button count to match your text or not, anyway a better approach regarding line count is detailled in this response: [How to get number of rows in <textarea > using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760629/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-textarea-using-javascript/1761203#1761203))

The things to remember regarding your main question is the usage of flex box, for  more information check this page: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In your case, we give the buttons container a display of flex and we ask it to wrap elements on several rows.

```
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Then we give the each button a width of 50% so that two buttons will completly fill one row and force the wrapping to occur.

```
button {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Note that there are other solutions to this problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in different ways: for example a possible solution would be to style elements by using **float**. In the following solution it is not used a div for container, but the layout is built up without such an element.

Also look carefully at the buttons and at the **customs** array and compare their content and their order: if you need the buttons to be shown into a different order you just need to adjust the order of the **elements** of such an array.

The following snippet is a working example, if you wish to see it in action, just click on the button **Run Code snippet** at the end of the snippet:

```js
let title = "This is the button "
let customs = ["Alfa","Bravo","Charlie","Delta",]

customs.forEach(function(c)
  {
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = title + c;
    btn.name = ">>>" + c;
    btn.className = "customButtons";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
);
```

```css
textArea
{
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 260px;
  width: 50%;
}

button
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
}

button, textArea
{
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<textarea class ="textArea" id="output" name="consl" readonly="true">Text content into text area</textarea>
```